# Data not set after fetch in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I try to fetch data from a server using `useEffect` hook in react 18.0.0. After the data is fetched, i want to set the state with the `useStat`e hook. I tried fetching the data with `.then()` syntax and the `async/await` syntax, but trying to log the state gives `undefined`.

**Variant 1) .then() -Syntax:**

```js
const fetchData = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:8080/user", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        setUser(data);
        console.log(user);
    });
}
```

**Variant 2) async/await-Syntax:**

```js
const asyncFetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/user", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);

    setUser(() => data);
    console.log(user);
}
```

**Effect hook and rendering:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
    asyncFetchData();
    fetchData();
}, []);

return (
    <>
        <span>{'' + user?.username}</span>
    </>
)
```

**Expected behaviour:**

The user object should be logged 4 times in the console and the username should be rendered on screen.

**Problems:**

The user object is logged two times when calling `console.log(data)` but not when calling `console.log(user)`. Also, the username is not rendered to the screen.

I've tried several answers on StackOverflow, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124214/data-not-set-after-fetch-in-react), but none of them did work.

How do I resolve this error?